# Why the code to write GUI application in c++ in Visual Studio is different than to console application?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, user-interface, visual-studio-2017

I am just a begginer in c++ and I am trying to learn it for my assignment. I've been learning how to write simple console applications for past few weeks and everything was going fine, until I tried use that knowledge to write GUI application using the visual editor. I created a gui, and when I double pressed the button, the code was similar to C++ but not exactly the same.

My question is, is there any way to still use the visual editor and use the standard c++ or do I have to learn the other (visual?) c++ to make the GUI usable?

Comment: The c++ standard library does not offer a gui library. So you will need to do that in either the platform native api i.e win32 or some 3rd party framework like qt. What you have used is likely the 1st option. It might not look like the c++ you have learned so far , but different libraries use different conventions e.g. `draw_widget` vs `DrawWidget`. The windows apis are also a c api, so you wont see objects or other c++ only features used.

Comment: _the code was similar to C++ but not exactly the same. _ And.. How wasn't the code C++? I developed GUIs with with WIN API, and I didn't notice anything that wasn't C++ there.

Comment: It is possible that you somehow let the Microsoft wizards to generate you application of  "C++/CLI" or "Managed C++" or whatever that Microsoft-specific not a C++ thing is called. Yes that is not C++ and you should avoid learning it since next to no one, even in Microsoft itself is using it.

Comment: @ÖöTiib: Absolutely, although on occasions (such as when building some interop from standard C++ to .NET) you're forced to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you *can* use standard C++ (or C for that matter) to write a GUI, but you will have to use the Windows API to draw your GUIs and handle the messages that your application will receive from the operating system.

But, Visual C++ is actually *helping* you here in giving you a template starting point application to which you can add your specific functionality. What it generates for you *is* C++, although it will be heavily littered with macros &c. which does make it appear quite alien on first inspection.

That all said, I believe the cool cats use Qt these days.